# Array as store in list in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Can we use Array Instead of Store for List in "sencha touch".

```
config:{
store: 'storeName',
scrollable: true,
itemTpl: '<div>{store_id}</div>'
}
```

This is config part of my store I want to use array for this list instead of store. 
Please provide some code.
Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can use array by setting array as list data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a List's data config property, which is an array of any fields you want, with some that will match your itemTpl for display.  It's basically a direct line into a List's store, which is created in the background for you without needing to be set. You will not need to define the store when setting the data directly.

It's probably best to set the data as an array in a defined store, and then set the store to the list, but you don't have to do it this way, and there are some cases you want to just use a simple array (see example below).

The Sencha Touch documentation shows examples of using the data array without a defined store [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List).

Sencha Touch 2.1.1 List data example

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
fullscreen: true,
itemTpl: '{title}',
data: [
    { title: 'Item 1' },
    { title: 'Item 2' },
    { title: 'Item 3' },
    { title: 'Item 4' }
]
```

});

You could also set data to an externally defined array, provided your list is created after the array is.  If this turns out to be a timing problem, then you can set the data with an array at any later time using

```
listname.setData(someArray);
```

Provided you got a proper reference to listname ahead of time.